# put response in ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

How can i get put response from ng-resource?

Following is my code:-

```
_userService.$update({id : $scope.User.UserId }, $scope.User, function(result){
   if (result.Status === "SUCCESS") {
     toastr.success(result.Message);
   };
});
```

Following is my factory:-

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('userService', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost/OJAdmin/api/users/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' , params: {id: '@id'}}
    });
  });
```

I am able to update the user but not getting any response in the result. I am getting proper response in chrome developer tool's network tab.

I am getting following response in chrome developer tool's network tab and record is edited successfully:-

```
{"Status":"SUCCESS","Message":"Saved Successfully."}
```

I am also getting error :-
**TypeError: (success || noop) is not a function**

I tried to log out to the console :-

```
console.log(_userService.$update({id : $scope.User.UserId }, $scope.User));
```

output is **Promise** Object

Then i tried following code:-

```
_userService.$update({id : $scope.User.UserId }, $scope.User).then(function(result){
 if (result.Status === "SUCCESS") {
         toastr.success(result.Message);
       };
});
```

I am getting same error **TypeError: (success || noop) is not a function**.

I also tried .$promise.then(function(data) { But no success

How can i get rid of this error and get proper response?

Comment: Have you defined the `$update` method?

Comment: doesn't it return a promise as well, so you could just chain `.then(function success() {})`

Comment: so what exactly is being returned from server when you inspect response ody in dev tools network? Have you tried `console.log(result)`?